# get current windows explorer path

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm using shell to open a windows explorer.
Let's say I go to Desktop and exit the windows explorer.
I would like to stock my path into a field to use later so that when I reopen my explorer it takes me back to the path I was at.

Here's what I have so far :

```
Dim Foldername As String
If ISNULL(Me.myfield.value) Then
    Foldername = ""
Else
    Foldername = ?
End If
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: To be honest I haven't got any further than this, and I can't find anything on internet about it so I'm pretty stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something along these lines (not tested fully) this will grab the windows explorer path.  Or look at using office dialogs, if you are just getting a file path perhaps...

```
'   Using Microsoft Internet Controls Reference

Sub c()

Dim w As SHDocVw.ShellWindows

Set w = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For i = 0 To w.Count - 1
    If w(i).Name = "Windows Explorer" Then
        currentdb.Execute "delete * from [mystorage]"
        currentdb.Execute "insert into [mystorage] (lastpath) values('" & w(i).LocationURL & "')"
        '      me.txtPrevExplorer.value=w(i).LocationURL 
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm quite new to vba, how would I then stock the URL location into a field like Me.myfield ?

Comment: Using the SQL that is in the code.  Did you get to grips with it in 4 minutes??????

Comment: You haven't upset me, was clear you'd put no effort in.   :)  Have a good day.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Is there a way to set the LocationURL to a different path?

Comment: Sorry, figured it out after realizing I could use the same commands as I do for IE. I used: w(i).navigate "C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/"